# Inbuilt popup menu for android 2.3

Tags: android-widget

I want to know if there is inbuilt popup menu available for android version 2.3? Any link suggestion will also be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I'm looking for the same thing and I end up with this link : http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-quickaction-dialog-in-android/

Interesting quotations :

> The QuickActions dialog is not included in standard Android SDK, so we have to create it manually.

and

> I found that the QuickContact dialog  uses private API call (com.android.internal.policy.PolicyManager) that does not exists in standard SDK

He implemented the QuickActions as an Open-Source project : https://github.com/lorensiuswlt/NewQuickAction3D